# Adding HTML file to React

Tags: html, reactjs, portfolio

I am recreating my portfolio using React. My previous portfolio, including the project files in it, used HTML, CSS, and vanilla JS.

The issue that I'm running into is after attaching the project file to my React project, I get an error message. I am including a screenshot of the error here. I have tried including the right loader as the error message states. I can't seem to find the right one or put it in the right spot.

[Error mesage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlhMv.png)

How do I get this previous HTML, CSS, JS file to open correctly from a React site?

Comment: So, have you googled that error to see what info there is about it? Have you looked into what a webpack "loader" is and why you would need one?

Comment: Moving to CLI for better support, as this is not a framework issue.